# Check if var is a List of any kind of objects

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I'm developing an application with .NET Framework 4.6.1 and C#.

I want to do this:

```
var val = actionArguments[key];
if (val is List<T> as class)
```

I want to check if `val` is a `List` of any kind of object but that statement doesn't compile.

How can I check if a variable declared as var is a List?

On my application var is `List<Code>`. `Code` is a custom class that I made. And `List` is `System.Generic.Collections`.

Comment: `val is IList`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if Property is List using Reflection in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617920/check-if-property-is-list-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Check out: [Testing if object is of generic type in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982487/testing-if-object-is-of-generic-type-in-c-sharp). The accepted answer will do to find out whether it's a `List<>`. Look further down for Jon Skeet's answer, if you want to test for derived classes as well. Things get harder here, and there may be edge cases. As people have suggested, checking the `IList` interface may be the best thing for your particular situation, just understand that's it not exactly the same thing as you asked to do.

Comment: If the answer is "yes, it is a list", what specifically do you intend to do with that knowledge? Knowing this might indicate the best way to answer your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `List<T>` is also implementing the non-generic `IList` interface, you can simply check

```
if (val is IList)
```

That's not to say that one can assume that anything that is `IList` is neccessarily a `List<T>`. But, in the case of the OP, that is having some indexer returning an `object` and needs to differ between specific (perhaps known) types, avoiding `GetType()` and relying on `is IList` is good enough *for this purpose*.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This gives true for anything which implements the non-generic interface, including arrays and many other types.

Answer (score 3):

A wordy comparison, but exact one: any `List<T>` is *generic type* and have the same generic type definition

```
if (val.GetType().IsGenericType && 
    val.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)) { 
  ...
}
```

Comparison with `IList` is not enough, an exotic counter example:

```
// generic, does implement IList, does not implement IList<T>
public class CounterExample<T>: IList {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Better: `val.GetType().IsGenericType && 
    val.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == 
    typeof(List<>)` You can use the syntax `List<>` for the type definition (one generic argument omitted). Similarly `Dictionary<,,>`, `Func<,,,>` etc. where the number of commas show the number of type parameters (minus one).

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: thank you for an excelent suggestion, `List<>` just slipped out of my mind; need more coffee.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(val is IList && val.GetType().IsGenericType &&
    val.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
{

}
```

Be aware you should check if `val.GetType()` is `Generic`, only val is `IList` will return true for `ArrayList` too.

**EDIT:**

Like *Jeppe Stig Nielsen* mention in comments, you should add the check `val.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)` to the if too.

Comment: Being aware of that, also be aware that many types other than `List<>`, including [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<>` and all the generic classes inheriting from it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx), will pass your test above.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen you are totally right, I never thought of that. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var val = actionArguments[key];
var codes = val as List<Code>;

if(codes == null)
{
    // val is not of the desired type, so exit, crash, whatever...
    return;
}

// work with your list of codes...
foreach(var code in codes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(code);
}
```