# check whether property type is of List<> type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to check whether property of a class is `List<>` or not.

I have tried using `IsAssignableFrom()` method to check whether it is a list or not.

I also have have tried using `GetInterfaces()` method.

but both the results return false.

my class is :

```
public class Product2 
{
    public List<ProductDetails2> ProductDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Using method `IsassignableFrom()`

```
var t = typeof(Product2).GetProperties();
foreach(var p in t) 
{
    var isEnumerable = typeof(Enumerable).IsAssignableFrom((p.PropertyType));
}
```

using method `GetInterfaces()`

```
var t = typeof(Product2).GetProperties();    
foreach(var p in t) 
{  
    var isEnumerable = parameter.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));
}
```

In both the scenarios above getting false for Product2.ProductDetails property.

Comment: Your `IsAssignableFrom` should work fine. Small typo I believe `typeof(IEnumerable)` is used not `typeof(Enumerable)`, right?

Comment: tried this :-    var isEnumerable = p.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(s => s.IsGenericType && s.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Enumerable));  still returns false.

Comment: I saw this on a similar post `if (var is IList)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421329/check-if-var-is-a-list-of-any-kind-of-objects

Comment: How about `property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( List<> )`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if var is a List of any kind of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421329/check-if-var-is-a-list-of-any-kind-of-objects)

Comment: @LeisenChang this works :-  `p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)`   thanks.

Comment: but why are `IsAssignableFrom()` and `GetInterfaces()` not working in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

> but why are `IsAssignableFrom()` and `GetInterfaces()` not working in this case ?

```
 var isEnumerable = typeof(Enumerable).IsAssignableFrom((p.PropertyType));
```

This does not work because `Enumerable` is a static class containing extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>`.

The concept of your second sample with `GetInterfaces()` seems to be correct; however, you use a `parameter` variable instead of the `foreach` loop variable `p`, which can be the problem.

---

Once I created a [couple of extension methods](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/blob/master/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/CoreLibraries/_Extensions/TypeExtensions.cs#L145) for this:

```
public static bool IsGenericTypeOf(this Type type, Type genericTypeDefinition)
    => type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericTypeDefinition;

public static bool IsImplementationOfGenericType(this Type type, Type genericTypeDefinition)
{
    if (!genericTypeDefinition.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        return false;

    // looking for generic interface implementations
    if (genericTypeDefinition.IsInterface)
    {
        foreach (Type i in type.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (i.Name == genericTypeDefinition.Name && i.IsGenericTypeOf(genericTypeDefinition))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // looking for generic [base] types
    for (Type t = type; type != null; type = type.BaseType)
    {
        if (t.Name == genericTypeDefinition.Name && t.IsGenericTypeOf(genericTypeDefinition))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Examples:

```
public class MyList : List<ProductDetails2> { }

//...

typeof(List<ProductDetails2>).IsGenericTypeOf(List<>); // true
typeof(MyList).IsGenericTypeOf(List<>); // false

typeof(MyList).IsImplementationOfGenericType(List<>); // true
typeof(MyList).IsImplementationOfGenericType(IEnumerable<>); // true
```